# Selenium webdriver for Ruby does nothing

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

As straightforward as it can be

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.send_keys "Hello WebDriver!"
element.submit

puts driver.title

driver.quit
```

This piece of code opens a blank browser and does nothing. What can it be?

Running on Mac Os X, Ruby 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a bug.

I've updated it from 2.42 to 2.43 and the problem is gone!